# Upload image -> canvas -> image - sizing issues

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I use file reader to read a user uploaded image, I size the canvas to the width and height of the image.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = e.target.result;
var canvas = $('#test-canvas')[0];
$('#test-canvas').width(img.width);
$('#test-canvas').height(img.height);
```

I then draw the image on to the canvas.

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0 canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

I then add the canvas to an image

```
var uploadImageObj = $('<img id="upload-img">');
uploadImageObj.attr('src', canvas.toDataURL());
uploadImageObj.appendTo('.template');
```

Later I plan to add reading exif data, and will rotate the image accordingly.

The problem I am having is that the image is always the default canvas size (300 x 150) - why? I need it to be the same size as the uploaded image?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `height` and the `width` of the `<canvas>`?

Comment: Yes, its in the code above.

Comment: A couple of things:
•Use img.onload to give the image time to load before trying to draw it.
•Change the canvas element width/height rather than the CSS width/height.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="row">
        <canvas hidden="hidden" id="canvas" width="1280" height="720" >
        </canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Downvoting a valid answer?